# Discord.py adding roles not picking up more than 1 word role

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_role("mod")
async def addrole(ctx, member : discord.Member, role : discord.Role):
    await member.add_roles(role)

@client.command()
@commands.has_role("mod")
async def removerole(ctx, member : discord.Member, role : discord.Role):
    await member.remove_roles(role)
```

This code works perfectly fine with roles with one word but once I try to use it with a role with 2 words it doesn't pick up the second word. For example if I asked it to add a role called "dark blue" then this pops up

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.RoleNotFound: Role "dark" not found.
```

is there a fix to this or do I have to redo roles in my discord server?

Comment: try to mention with that role or put in quote marks the role's name.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that are going on.

1. If the command parameter `role` should be a string, you will need to use `discord.utils.get()` to get a `discord.Role` object.

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_role("mod")
async def addrole(ctx, member : discord.Member, role : str):
    roleobj = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=role)
    if roleobj is not None:
        await member.add_roles(roleobj)

@client.command()
@commands.has_role("mod")
async def removerole(ctx, member : discord.Member, role : str):
    roleobj = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=role)
    if roleobj is not None:
        await member.remove_roles(role)
```

2. If the command parameter `role` should be a `discord.Role` object, members will have to mention the role when invoking the command.

`!addrole @MemberName @RoleName` or `!removerole @MemberName @RoleName`

---

### If (1) is the intended usage

If you check out the documentation for the [`discord.ext.commands` framework](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#), you'll see a note from the developers on passing positional arguments which contain spaces:

> To make use of a word with spaces in between, you should quote it

So, everything which you have currently set up should work perfectly fine. It would just be a matter of telling your guild members that role names that contain spaces should be quoted. For example:

`!addrole @MemberName "dark blue"`

or

`!removerole @MemberName "dark blue"`

---

### If (2) is the intended usage

This is just be a matter of telling your guild members that roles should be mentioned when using the commands.

Answer (score 0):

Discord.py parses arguments by spaces. For example:

```py
@commands.command()
async def say(self, ctx, to_say: str):
    await ctx.send(to_say)

# !say hello world
# hello
```

This can be solved in two ways:

The first is to change the command to accept more than one word:

```py
@commands.command()
async def say(self, ctx, *, to_say: str):
    await ctx.send(to_say)

# !say hello world
# hello world
```

You can also put arguments inside of quotes, and discord.py won't split them.

```py
@commands.command()
async def say(self, ctx, to_say: str):
   await ctx.send(to_say)

# !say "hello world"
# hello world
```

So in your case:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_role("mod")
async def addrole(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, role : discord.Role):
    await member.add_roles(role)

@client.command()
@commands.has_role("mod")
async def removerole(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, role : discord.Role):
    await member.remove_roles(role)

# This will now accept dark blue as a role, instead of only taking dark
```

Also, a note on the other answer. It is not true that you have to mention the role, commands.RoleConverter will accept names, ids, or mentions. There is no reason to use anything except discord.Role for converters in commands.